# How to make multiple descriptions in a method on Magritte

Tags: smalltalk, meta, pharo

In Magritte I can define a description method that returns one description:

```
MyEntity>>nameDescription
    <magritteDescription>
    ^ MAStringDescription new
                          accessor: #street;
                          label: 'Street';
                          priority: 100;
                          yourself
```

But can I return more than one description, in an array, for example? I thought maybe `magritteContainer` pragma might work, but looking at the code it seems that Magritte looks for only one method annotated like this in the object hierarchy, so I am not sure using it is the right way. Is there a recommended way (if one at all) of doing multiple descriptions in one single method?

Answer (score 1):

You are expected to mostly have one description for each field/property/relation. Then the standard mechanism of collecting all descriptions in the container works very well. Nothing is stopping you from adding multiple descriptions for a field, and building up components that only use a subset of these descriptions, however. In QCMagritte we chained the visitors, so an access control mechanism could remove certain descriptions, and make others read-only. Then a translation visitor would translate all labels, and only then would the html generating visitor apply itself.

Comment: I am not thinking on adding multiple descriptions to a single field, but instead describe multiple fields in the same method.

Comment: Describing multiple fields in the same method would likely be a bad idea. If you have multiple fields that only differ in accessor/label, you might want to create a special MADescription subclass for it. Otherwise I'm not sure how you'd keep your methods small

Comment: Either or not it is a good idea, which is debatable, is it possible? How? I am actually trying to experiment, but I want to be less intrusive as possible. Looking at `MABasicObject` that don't seems possible.